Why is it automatically written to a new line when the line is full?
Why does Visual Studio 2022 (I wrote it as an example because you encountered these problems in this version) when writing code in one column, if this line is full, it automatically switches to the second line. If the next rows are full, the same situation is repeated. You can see from the sign in the picture.


Are you asking why Visual Studio is doing this automatically (and, implicitly, how to turn it off), or why the creators of Visual Studio decided to make this a feature in the first place?

This is only about how the code is displayed - it hasn't actually changed what's in the source file.
It's an option - in VS, go to the Tools menu, select Options, then under "Text editor", "All languages", "General" find the "Word wrap" setting and uncheck it:

